# Results of Sub query in one column? Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, subquery, multiple-results

I want to know if there is a way to get multiple results of a subquery in one column for the query...
Something like this:

```
otherid | resultsFromsomeData
1       | 1,2,3   
2       | 1,5  
3       | No Data
```

I was trying something like this:

```
select o.otherID, 
CASE WHEN (select otherID from someData where someid=o.otherID)>1 THEN
       ''||(select otherID from someData where someid=o.otherID)||'' /*here I am*/
   WHEN (select otherID from someData where someid=o.otherID)<1 THEN
       'No Data'
   END 
as resultsFromsomeData
from OtherData o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a simple join and group by:

```
select o.other_id, 
       coalesce(string_agg(sd.other_id, ','), 'No data') as results_from_some_data
from other_data o
  join some_data d on o.other_id = d.someid
group by o.other_id;
```

Comment: Well, I didn't know either String_AGG and Coalesce
Thanks a lot! saved my life!